# Images on MVC Form loading but not visible in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, azure-web-app-service

This is a basic MVC view hosted in an Azure App Service application. When we load our form some of the images are intermittently not loading or partially loading (you will see only half the image). You can see my example image below.

Sometimes the images are completely missing, sometimes partially rendered.  However, as soon as I refresh the page, or even just resize the window without any refreshing, the images fully display.  I checked in dev tools and they're all completely loaded they just do not show (see below).  So after a window resize nothing at all changes in the network tab, there has been no network activity, but the images are all suddenly completely visible. If I CTRL+F5 then some images are not visible or partially visible again, but sometimes different ones.

This is only occurring with Chrome. Edge and Firefox do not have this issue.  We have tried this on multiple machines in different environments.

Here is what the image tags look like, including the div tag that it's contained in:

```
<div style="display: inline-flex; width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">
    <img border="0" src="https://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/productimages/a1aa1aa1-1aa1-11a1-1111-aa1111111aa1/STAR100.png" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; margin: auto; ">
    <br>
</div>
```

We tried appending a unique tag to the end of the image link to force it not to cache, we added no cache to the page, we tried adding a loading easy property, and nothing so far is working.

[image: Partial Images]

[image]

Comment: I also just for testing tried to add a window.reload to see if that refresh would work, it flicked but did not.  Oddly, different images disappeared and showed when it refreshes.  I tried with both window.reload(false) and window.reload(true).   Also tried window.resizeBy() to see if it would work.  No luck.  The only thing that consistently works is manually resizing the window or F5 (but NOT CTRL+F5).

Comment: Interestingly, I am working with another developer and he was not seeing the issue (although several others were).  He was running Chrome 81.0.4044.138 (64-bit).  Once he updated to the latest version, 83.0.4103.6 (64-bit), it started occurring.

Comment: One more comment, we loaded all the images locally and it still happened. So it does not appear to be related to Azure Blob being the image source.

Comment: Turning hardware acceleration off "fixes" the issue.  Of course, this is the default setting and we can't tell everyone using the site to do this.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out what this is. While looking through some of the code where the image is actually stored to azure we noticed that it was "hard-coding" the image as a .png file.  So the user was sending links for .jpg files which were pulled and then uploaded to azure blob as .png.   What's odd is that this was working just fine for all browsers and chrome until the most recent update.  After this most recent update, we started getting this issue.

So, once we downloaded the images, converted them to be real PNG files, and re-uploaded the problem was resolved.  It was a weird anomaly on our end that was not really seen until this latest chrome update exposed it.